# How can I insert a record in join table of a many to many hibernate annotation?

Tags: hibernate

I have many to many relationship between two table and generate new join table in hibernate
now how can I insert a record in join table by updatation of both table
say two table are tbluser and tbldomain

I have to insert record in tbluserdomainrelation from both side (that is from tbluser and tbldomain)

At present I can insert record in join table only when I save or update tbluser but I want
record to be inserted when I update relationship in domain table also

In `user.class` I have written

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = VirtualDomain.class, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)

@JoinTable(name = "tblUserDomainRel", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userid"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "domainid"))

public Set<VirtualDomain> getVirtualdomainset() {
        return virtualdomainset;
}

public void setVirtualdomainset(Set<VirtualDomain> virtualdomainset) {
        this.virtualdomainset = virtualdomainset;
}
```

While in domain table I have entry

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "virtualdomainset", targetEntity = User.class)

public Set<User> getUserset() {
        return userset;
}

public void setUserset(Set<User> userset) {
        this.userset = userset;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I suspect you may be falling at the first hurdle:

As has been previously stated, Hibernate will update the object that you call `update()` on and then cascade down to any subsequent objects that require updating, following the rules you specify in the `@Cascade` attribute.

The problem is that your `User` class owns the relationship and adding a `User` object to the `VirtualDomain.userset` collection does not alter the `User` object in any way.  Thus even with a cascade, Hibernate will not update the `User` object as it doesn't think that it has to.

Instead, when you add an object to the `VirtualDomain.userset` collection, ensure that the `VirtualDomain` is added to the `User.virtualdomainset` collection as well.

```
// given a VirtualDomain object
VirtualDomain domain = getSession().load( VirtualDomain.class, 1234 );

// and a User object
User user = getSession().load( User.class, 5678 );

// add the User to the VirtualDomain
domain.getUserset().add( user );
// but also add the VirtualDomain to the user
user.getVirtualdomainset().add( domain );

// update the VirtualDomain and the Cascade settings will also update the User
getSession().update( domain );
```

In cases like this I find it useful to provide a helper method for adding objects to collections, rather than using direct access to the collections themselves. e.g.

```
public class VirtualDomain {

    Set userset;

   /* snip... */

    public void addUser( User user ) {
        getUserset().add( user );
        user.getVirtualdomainset().add( this );
    }
}
```

Although it's worth remembering the advice of the Hibernate fore-fathers:

> "In a real system, you may not have a many-to-many association. Our experience is that there is almost always other information that must be attached to each link... the best way... is via an intermediate *assocation class*." (Java Persistence With Hibernate, p. 297/298 , ISBN 1-932394-88-5)

Answer (score 0):

How do your classes look like ?

I suppose you have a class Domain and a class User.
In the Domain class, suppose you have a Users collection.   Add a User object to the Users collection, and call SaveOrUpdate on the Domain object.
Also make sure that you've specified the correct cascading option (for instance cascading="save-update".

That 's a bit the big picture.  We need more detailed information on what is not working.

Comment: in domain bean i have mapping
 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "virtualdomainset", targetEntity = User.class)
 public Set<User> getUserset() {
  return userset;
 }

in user bean i have mapping 

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = VirtualDomain.class, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(name = "tblUserDomainRel", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userid"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "domainid"))
 public Set<VirtualDomain> getVirtualdomainset() {
  return virtualdomainset;
 }

Comment: there is setter method in both class but i have not included bacause of size limit.
i can insert correctly by calling save or update method of user but i can't insert record by calling save or update method of domain table.
so how can i achieve that.

Comment: You can edit your question in order to provide more details.  That's a lot more readable as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have made User class the owner of the relationship.  If you want to go the other way then you need to switch their mapping so that Domaintable has the @JoinTable.  Or you have to manually force it by using @PrePersist or @PreUpdate on Domaintable to forcefully call the update on the User which would insert the row into the join table.  I am sure there are other ways to accomplish it, but those are the two that come to mind.

```
@PreUpdate example :

@EntityListeners( Domaintable.class )
@Entity
public class Domaintable
{

User  user;

....

@PreUpdate
public void onPreUpdate( DomainTable domainTable )
{
   if( domainTable.getUser() != null )
   {
       entitymanager.update( domainTable.getUser() );
    }
}

....

}
```

Comment: how can i use prePersist annotation please provide me some idea what value i have to assign in this tag